# Tokenizing a list of lists

Tags: python, csv, twitter

I'm trying to tokenize a csv file of scrapped tweets. I uploaded the csv files as lists

```
with open('recent_tweet_purex.csv', 'r') as purex:
reader_purex = csv.reader(purex)
purex_list = list(reader_purex)
```

now the tweets are in lists as such

```
["b'I miss having someone to talk to all night..'"], ["b'Pergunte-me 
qualquer coisa'"], ["b'RT @Caracolinhos13: Tenho a 
tl cheia dessa merda de quem vos visitou nas \\xc3\\xbaltimas horas'"], 
["b'RT @B24pt: #CarlosHadADream'"], ['b\'"Tudo tem 
um fim"\''], ["b'RT @thechgama: stalkear as curtidas \\xc3\\xa9 um caminho 
sem volta'"], ["b'Como consegues fumar 3 purexs seguidas? \\xe2\\x80\\x94 
Eram 2 purex e mix...'"]
```

I have nltk imported as well as with the following packages

```
 from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
 import string
 from nltk.corpus import stopwords
 from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
 from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
 nltk.download('punkt')
```

I tried using

```
 purex_words = word_tokenize(purex_words)
```

to to tokenize but I keep getting errors

Any help?

Comment: It will be more helpful if you tell us the errors you're getting.

Comment: You should flatten the list.

Comment: NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-5bb6d314f393> in <module>()
----> 1 purex_words = word.tokenize(purex_list)

NameError: name 'word' is not defined

Comment: @user9270834 error says you are calling `word.tokenize` not `word_tokenize`. You have a syntax error. Change the dot (**.**) to underscore (**_**).

Comment: Oh wait, I messed up explaining how i messed up

Comment: the error for word_tokenize(purex_list) is
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Answer (score 0):

You are passing arrays to the `word_tokenize` function and it expects `string or bytes-like object`. If you feed it with strings it will work. Quick example.

```
purex_words = [['I miss having someone to talk to all night..'], ['Pergunte-me qualquer coisa'],
```

['RT @Caracolinhos13: Tenho a tl cheia dessa merda de quem vos visitou nas \xc3\xbaltimas horas'], ['RT @B24pt: #CarlosHadADream'], ["Tudo tem um fim"],
["RT @thechgama: stalkear as curtidas \xc3\xa9 um caminho sem volta"], ['Como consegues fumar 3 purexs seguidas? \xe2\x80\x94 Eram 2 purex e mix...']]

```
for sentence in purex_words:
    print(word_tokenize(sentence[0])) # this looks ugly to me
```

You could flatten the list before looping over the sentences. **Note that I added an external `[]` to your lists**.

```
flat_list = [item for sublist in purex_words for item in sublist]
for sentence in flat_list:
    print(word_tokenize(sentence))
```

The result looks something like this.

```
['I', 'miss', 'having', 'someone', 'to', 'talk', 'to', 'all', 'night..']
['Pergunte-me', 'qualquer', 'coisa']
['RT', '@', 'Caracolinhos13', ':', 'Tenho', 'a', 'tl', 'cheia', 'dessa', 'merda', 'de', 'quem', 'vos', 'visitou', 'nas', '\\xc3\\xbaltimas', 'horas']
['RT', '@', 'B24pt', ':', '#', 'CarlosHadADream']
['Tudo', 'tem', 'um', 'fim']
['RT', '@', 'thechgama', ':', 'stalkear', 'as', 'curtidas', '\\xc3\\xa9', 'um', 'caminho', 'sem', 'volta']
['Como', 'consegues', 'fumar', '3', 'purexs', 'seguidas', '?', '\\xe2\\x80\\x94', 'Eram', '2', 'purex', 'e', 'mix', '...']
```

Comment: That's progress, thanks. The tweets are now all in their own list with each word tokenized how would I aggregate all those tokenized words into one list?

Comment: Also, I realized you have some extra characters that might be not necessary, maybe because you were trying to avoid the error? I'm referring to the excess of quote symbols `["b'Pergunte-me qualquer coisa'"]`. The previous could be simplified as `['Pergunte-me qualquer coisa']`. No need for `"b`.

Comment: The last issue is how to combine those lists into one list without the "b

Comment: what do you mean? In the `flat_list` for example? It's redundant, but you could do `flat_list = [str(item) for sublist in purex_words for item in sublist]` . This gets rid of `b`. Which Python version are you using btw, 2 or 3? For further information you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal), but that wouldn't be in the scope of the original question =)

Comment: Oh, I see in your specific case you have nested quotes in quotes, something like this `"b'` at the beginning and `' "` in the end. I'm sure there is a better way to do this, but a quick way to get rid of it, given that it's always the same format, to substring the part you want to get `flat_list = [item[2:-1] for sublist in purex_words for item in sublist]
`. But it's not very elegant, I would definitely check the way you obtain the text, the way you store it and the way you read it again from your `.csv`!